# Difference in shape of tensor torch.Size([]) and torch.Size([1]) in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am new to pytorch. While playing around with tensors I observed 2 types of tensors-

```
tensor(58)
tensor([57.3895])
```

I printed their shape and the output was respectively -

```
torch.Size([])
torch.Size([1])
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6):

You can play with tensors having the single scalar value like this:

```
import torch

t = torch.tensor(1)
print(t, t.shape) # tensor(1) torch.Size([])

t = torch.tensor([1])
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([1]) torch.Size([1])

t = torch.tensor([[1]])
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([[1]]) torch.Size([1, 1])

t = torch.tensor([[[1]]])
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([[[1]]]) torch.Size([1, 1, 1])

t = torch.unsqueeze(t, 0)
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([[[[1]]]]) torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1])

t = torch.unsqueeze(t, 0)
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([[[[[1]]]]]) torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

t = torch.unsqueeze(t, 0)
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([[[[[[1]]]]]]) torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

#squize dimension with id 0
t = torch.squeeze(t,dim=0)
print(t, t.shape) # tensor([[[[[1]]]]]) torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

#back to beginning.
t = torch.squeeze(t)
print(t, t.shape) # tensor(1) torch.Size([])

print(type(t)) # <class 'torch.Tensor'>
print(type(t.data)) # <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

Tensors, do have a size or shape. Which is the same. Which is actually a class `torch.Size`.
You can write `help(torch.Size)` to get more info.
Any time you write `t.shape`, or `t.size()` you will get that size info.

The idea of tensors is they can have different compatible size dimension for the data inside it including `torch.Size([])`.

Any time you unsqueeze a tensor it will add another dimension of 1.
Any time you squeeze a tensor it will remove dimensions of 1, or in general case all dimensions of one.

Answer (score 5):

First one has `0` size dimension, second one has `1` dimension, PyTorch tries to make both compatible (`0` size can be regarded similarly to `float` or a-like although I haven't really met the case where it's explicitly needed, except what [@javadr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62978095/10886420) shown in his answer below).

Usually you would use `list` to initialize it though, [see here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) for more information.

Comment: I think this is not incorrect, and it means a tensor with dimension `0`.

Comment: look at the `fill_`. It just takes a 0-dimension value tensor. 
So,  you can not use it like `t.fill_(torch.tensor([1]))`. It totally wrong and produces the following error:
`RuntimeError: fill_ only supports 0-dimension value tensor but got tensor with 1 dimensions.`
But it is applicable to use like like below:
`t.fill_(torch.tensor(1)).`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation of `tensor` in `pytorch`:

```
Docstring:
tensor(data, dtype=None, device=None, requires_grad=False, pin_memory=False) -> Tensor

Constructs a tensor with :attr:`data`.
```

then it describes what the data is:

```
Args:
    data (array_like): Initial data for the tensor. Can be a list, tuple,
        NumPy ``ndarray``, scalar, and other types.
```

As you can see the `data` could be a scalar (which is a data with the dimension of zero).

Thus, in response to your question the `tensor(58)`  is a tensor with dimension `0` and the `tensor([58])` is a tensor with dimension `1`.