# What is the difference between Tensor.size and Tensor.shape in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

What is the difference between `Tensor.size` and `Tensor.shape` in Pytorch?
I want to get the number of elements and the dimensions of Tensor. For example for a tensor with the dimensions of 2 by 3 by 4 I expect 24 for number of elements and (2,3,4) for dimension.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in shape of tensor torch.Size(\[\]) and torch.Size(\[1\]) in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856996/difference-in-shape-of-tensor-torch-size-and-torch-size1-in-pytorch)

Comment: thanks. No, it differs

Comment: For number of elements, I used `torch.numel(var)`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`.shape` is an alias for `.size()`, and was added to more closely match `numpy`, see this discussion [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5544).

Comment: Where does the doc mention `.shape` ? (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) It is confusing.

Answer (score 6):

.shape is an attribute of the tensor whereas size() is a function. They both return the same value.